# Adding second router to home network via Ethernet cable

Tags: router, home-networking

I want to add a router and wifi hotspot to a home network, via a long Ethernet cable installed to the main router. I used a Dlink DIR505 from the cupboard, but it won't work. I believe the reason is that it has the same internal IP address as the home router, 198.162.0.1. So I changed it to 198.162.0.2 and 198.162.1.1. But then I can't even connect to the Dlink to set it up,let alone connect to the internet, necessitating a factory reset. I've also tried to use a Dlink DIR826L (overkill, but I had one spare). Exactly the same thing happens. I know I could just use the DIR826 as a switch instead of as a router,but I also want to change the DNS settings.

Comment: Connect as follows:  (1) Hook up LAN port on second router to LAN port on network. (2) Give the second router a Static IP Address on the main network.  (3) Turn DHCP OFF on the second router.  Restart (not reset) the routers and test.

Comment: First comment is good. Keep everything on the same /24 subnet i.e. 192.168.0.xxx as well.